# How to track the moment when data is pulled from the socket write buffer to transport level? C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

how to track the moment when data is pulled from the socket write buffer to transport level on C#? Or thread automatically waits until data from socket write buffer does not move to the transport level? On actionscript 3 this moment can be tracked through the **OutputProgressEvent.OUTPUT_PROGRESS**. Do C# have analog?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to an application buffer, data has been moved from there into the transport layer, i.e. into the socket send buffer, when the write method returns.

If on the other hand you refer to the socket send buffer, it is already in the transport layer, so your question wouldn't make sense, and there is nothing short of a driver interface that would tell you when data went from there to the NIC.

I suspect what the OUTPUT_PROGRESS event you mention does is the former.